# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling

I want to be able to ssh into work-pc that is behind a restrictive firewall from home-pc.

Work-pc openssh version

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

I use this command on work-pc:
ssh -p443 -fNTR 0.0.0.0:6333:localhost:443 username@XX.XX.XX.XX

I use this command on home-pc:

ssh -v -p 6333 localhost

output from home-pc:

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 6333.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

The work-pc reponds to home-pc with:

```
connect_to localhost port 443: failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see related issues, because this is recent bug, i have the same problem without exit. i dont know if the bad configuration of your router or something like this, but dont working for me.

See related issues

[Bug reported in redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1313979)

[Bug kernel bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111041)